# Django Foreign Key Constraint failed after blank = True

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I get an Integrity error,  Foreign Key Constraint failed. I have the following function I am trying to run:

```
if request.method == "POST":
        #Get token
        access_token = AccessToken.objects.get(token = request.POST.get('access_token'),
            expires__gt = timezone.now())
        #Get profile
        customer = access_token.user.customer

        # Check if customer has a order that is not delivered
        if Order.objects.filter(customer = customer).exclude(status = Order.DELIVERED):
            return JsonResponse({"status": "fail", "error": "Your Last Order must be completed"})

        # Check Address
        if not request.POST["address"]:
            return JsonResponse({"status": "failed", "error": "Address is required."})

        # Ger Order Details
        order_details = json.loads(request.POST["order_details"])

        order_total = 0
        for meal in order_details:
            order_total += Meal.objects.get(id = meal["meal_id"]).price * meal["quantity"]

        if len(order_details)>0:
            # Step 1 - Create an Order
            order = Order.objects.create(
                customer = customer,
                restaurant_id = request.POST["restaurant_id"],
                total = order_total,
                status = Order.PENDING,
                address = request.POST["address"]
            )
            # Step 2 - Create Order details
            for meal in order_details:
                OrderDetails.objects.create(
                    order = order,
                    meal_id = meal["meal_id"],
                    quantity = meal["quantity"],
                    sub_total = Meal.objects.get(id = meal["meal_id"]).price * meal["quantity"]
                )
            return JsonResponse({"status": "success"})
```

Here is my order class:

```
Class Order(models.Model):
    PENDING = 1
    COOKING = 2
    READY = 3
    ONTHEWAY = 4
    DELIVERED = 5

    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        (PENDING, "Pending"),
        (COOKING, "Cooking"),
        (READY, "Ready"),
        (ONTHEWAY, "On The Way"),
        (DELIVERED, "Delivered"),
    )


    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    restaurant = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    driver = models.ForeignKey(Driver, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank = True, null = True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    total = models.IntegerField()
    status = models.IntegerField(choices = STATUS_CHOICES)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now)
    picked_at = models.DateTimeField(blank = True, null = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

I previously got an error because Driver was not null so I added `blank = True, null = True`. Now it gives the Foreign Key Contraint Error.

I am testing the function is postman, and I do not define the driver anywhere, the driver is to be added later not while the function is called.

This is my views.py

```
def restaurant_add_meal(request):
    form = MealForm()

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = MealForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            meal = form.save(commit=False)
            meal.restaurant = request.user.restaurant
            meal.save()
            return redirect(restaurant_meal)
    return render(request, 'restaurant/add_meal.html', {
        "form": form
        })
```

Comment: did you create & applied migration?

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko yes

Comment: why do you the integrity error is relevant to Driver? It sounds like you're trying to store a value into a foreign key (which is not Driver necessarily) which does not have a matching record in the target table

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko I didn't get this error until I modified the driver foreign key parameters in Order class. But likely that the other error occurred first.

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko Log says it is in  order = Order.objects.create(, line 69

Comment: yes but you were not sending the same data back then. So again - how do you know it's not because you are storing mismatching value to some other foreign key? Namely this: `restaurant_id = request.POST["restaurant_id"]`. [Write a test](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/testing/overview/) to confirm/deny you hypothesis.

Answer (score 0):

I changed `restaurant_id = request.POST["restaurant_id"]` to

```
restaurant = Restaurant.objects.get(pk = request.POST["restaurant_id"])
```

and the error is fixed.